# How to retrieve the mode of an image transformation from its name?

Tags: image-transforms, image, assetfilemodel, twigextension

I work on a portfolio with a large number of images with very high sizes and a lot of images transforms. The server on which this site is hosted reach these limits (images generations process are generally blocked), so I would like to experiment with [imgix](http://www.imgix.com) in order to move the transformations of images in the cloud.

I need to tell imgix how to crop images and I prefer to define my transformation types in the Control Panel rather than in the templates. How can I retrieve the mode of an image transformation from its his name?

Is there something like `{{ craft.assets.getMode('myTransformName') }}` ? I haven't found a method for this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible out of the box, unfortunately. Asset transforms can be pulled by using the [AssetsTransformService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/AssetTransformsService#getTransformByHandle-detail), but Craft doesn't expose that service to Twig (unlike the [AssetsService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/AssetsService), which is what you're working with when you're using `craft.assets`).

What you could do is to [create a simple, custom plugin](https://pluginfactory.io/) exposing the AssetsTransformsService to Twig by adding the following to a [Variable](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/variables) class in your plugin:

```
public function assetTransforms()
{
    return craft()->assetTransforms;
}
```

Then, you'd be able to do something like this in your templates:

```
{% set transform = craft.myPluginHandle.assetTransforms.getTransformByHandle('myTransformName') %}
<p>The mode is {{ transform.mode }}</p>
```